# In pinescript v5: I want to get the bar number of the highest value. for example ---> ta.highest(rsi,14)

Tags: line

I cannot seem to find a code that returns the bar_index or bar_number corresponding to the highest value in a series.

I tried searching online but no luck.

I cannot seem to find a code that returns the bar_index or bar_number corresponding to the highest value in a series.

I tried searching online but no luck.